# Flutter show changes to variable

Tags: flutter, double, state, provider

I have a public double called minuteValue and minuteValue gets modified by two different classes, but when I change minute in class1 the changes are not displayed in class2. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the state of the app, changing a value will not update the Widget with the new value. I suggest looking into bloc/GetX

Comment: Ok thank you I know that State Managment will solve the problem but hoped there is a other possiblity.

Comment: you can pass ```setState``` function from class to class, it will also work that way